# Android View Flipper

Tags: android

I have two Activity ActivityOne and ActivtyTwo.This two has Corresponding XML Files main.xml and main1.xml.if i press the next button in ActivityOne ActivityTwo appears with animation.is it possible through viewflipper

Answer (score 1):

You can check this sample out

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

You can use `<include layout="@layout/mylayout" />` to split it as multiple layouts